# If product of finite elements in a ring is a unit then can we say each element as unit

Tags: ring-theory

In a ring If product of finite elements is a unit then can we say each element as unit

For ex., if $q_1 q_2 ... q_m$ is a unit, then can we say each of $q_i$ $\forall i$ is a unit
how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general. The ring of linear transformations of an infinite dimensional vector space contains elements $a,b$ such that $ab=1$ but $ba\neq 1$, and neither $a$ or $b$ is invertible. The linear transformations $a$ and $b$ can be given as "shift" operators that move the elements in the basis, such that one shifts them right and one shifts them left.

But if the ring is commutative, then obviously the answer is yes. You even have the inverses after you find $q_1q_2\ldots q_mu=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the product $q_1 q_2....q_m$ is a unit in Ring $R$ which means that there exists some $u\in$ $R$ such that $q_1 q_2....q_m u$ =$1$,where $1$ is the identity in ring $R$.

Now clearly $q_1$ is a unit in $R$.

And $q_2....q_m u$ = $q_1^{-1}$ or  $q_2....q_m u q_1$=$1$ and by similar arguements we can say that $q_2$ is unit in $R$ and so on....

Hence each of $q_i$ $\forall i$ is a unit.

Comment: Note that you are assuming the ring to be commutative. If it is not, your arguments will no longer work.

Comment: Exactly!! Thanks for correcting me.