# Units in a Commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a commutative ring $R$ with unity and $a, b \in R$, if $ab$ is a unit, are $a$ and $b$ units as well? My intuition is that they must be, but I'm not sure how to see that.

Comment: If you  let $c$ be an inverse of $ab$, could you write down an inverse of $a$?

Comment: This is completely answered by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2474895/29335), although I'll refrain from duplicating it even though it is completely covered in both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If $ab$ is a unit in $R$, then

$ab \mid 1_R, \tag 1$

which means there is some $c \in R$ with

$(ab)c = 1; \tag 2$

but then

$a(bc) = (ab)c = 1_R, \tag 3$

so

$a \mid 1_R, \tag 4$

and $a$ is a unit in $R$.  Also,

$b(ac) = (ba)c = (ab)c = 1_R, \tag 4$

so $b$ is a unit as well.

This little result clearly extends to the assertion that $a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n$ a unit implies each $a_i$ is a unit too.

Comment: If you'd just like to use the divisibility argument, then just use transitivity:  $a|ab|1\implies a|1$.  Or one can write out $(ab)c=c(ab)=1$ implies $a(bc)=(bc)a=1$. Writing it this way is kind of mashing up the two approaches.

Comment: @rschwieb:  I almost wrote it out using transitivity but it strikes me that our OP is not only new to this web site, but to rings in general and I wanted to make the logic as clear as possible, though indeed doing so cost some brevity.

Comment: I know... your answer is pretty good (+1), and I'm not complaining it's long, it's just (IMO) the logic is muddled slightly by being bracketed by the divisibility idea. (2) and (3) with the addition of "$(bc)a=1$" would make as solid, straightforward logical proof directly from first principles. Then you could follow up with (1) and (4) next to each other saying "if you prefer to think about units being divisors of $1$ then you can leverage the fact divisibility works thusly..."

Comment: At least, that's what I'd do to try to get a crystal-clear logical approach (or two!) in this post. Up to you to adopt it or not :) Regards

Comment: @rschwieb:  I guess my ignorance is exposed:  I though units were *defined* as being divisors of $1$?

Comment: it’s an equivalent way of saying it, yes, but I think usually it is not introduced that way.

Comment: @rschwieb:  OK, I'll bite:  educate me, how would you do it?

Comment: I just mean that the word “divisible” and the symbol $|$ are not usually used at first. Your 2 and 3 already cover the elementary solution, mostly.

Comment: @rschwieb:  Gotcha.  Thanks.

Comment: @rschwieb:  by the way, your vote got me the "ring-theory" badge!

Comment: congrats ! ${}{}{}$

Comment: @rschwieb:  Thank you, thank you!  And for my next trick . . . .